# spring-security decouple roles and permissions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I'm currently working on a `spring-boot 2.0` `REST` backend for a web-application. The `spring-boot` application receives `OAuth2` AccessTokens for authentication with application specific roles for authorization. Now I want to secure various `REST` endpoints and methods based on the `OAuth2` roles. I'm loking for a solution that does not couple my code directly to the roles, **not** like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")`.

In addition to the authorization, the `REST` endpoints should also return customized results (e.g. if the request contains an valid `OAuth2` token with the role 'company_A_internal', the response should contain a result-set filtered on 'company_A').

**What I've already accomplished so far:**

1. The authentication based on the `OAuth2` token with the help of the `spring-security`
2. The mapping of the `OAuth2` token roles to the `spring-security` `GrantedAuthorities` so that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()` returns the former roles

**What I'm looking for:**

Based on the roles (now stored in the `GrantedAuthorities`) the `REST` endpoints should be secured by a separate mechanism. I did some research and came across a really interesting [article](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-secure-role-based-access-control-rbac-for-r).

I would like to implement something similar to this (e.g. as a separate roles_config.yml):

```
order_manager:
  '/orders':
    - 'GET'
    - 'POST'
    - 'PUT'
    - 'DELETE'
order_editor:
  '/orders':
    - 'GET'
    - 'POST'
    - 'PUT'
order_inspector:
  '/orders':
    - 'GET'
```

Afterwards I'd only have to implement something like this in the `spring-boot` context:

```
@Secured
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public void updateOrder (Order order) {
  Order updatedOrder = process(order);
  return updatedOrder;
}
```

How will this work in the context of `spring-security`? Is there any possible way of implementing this on top of my current setup?

I appreciate any kind of recommendations and help and will gladly answer to comments and further questions.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea and the blog is not really helpful. First: In a yaml file typos for URL are very likely. Second: If you change the URL in your code (annotation) you have to always change the yaml file, too.  BTW: OAuth2 doesn't have any roles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/vsfexperts/rbac . You'll have to configure the mapping from role to privileges and annotate your endpoints with @Secured("some_privilege").
Just keep in mind that this is static and doesn't allow content based security e.g. access to /orders/5 won't be restricted to user x, who's the owner of 5. It will only be restricted by a role, which has the privilege annotated with /orders endpoint (e.g. @Secured("some_privilege")).